# Getting the visible area of a QGraphicsScene in QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview

If I set a pixmap to a `QGraphicsScene` that is larger that the window, it will add scrollbars, So is it possible to get what is displayed in the `QGraphicsView` ?

Also Is there any event raised while scrolling and changeing the displayed area ?

Here is a screen of what I'm talking about:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can determine visible area in the scene coordinates as follows:

```
QRect viewport_rect(0, 0, view->viewport()->width(), view->viewport()->height());
QRectF visible_scene_rect = view->mapToScene(viewport_rect).boundingRect();
```

You can use `QGraphicsItem::mapFromScene` to convert scene coordinates to item coordinates is necessary.

You can use `view->horizontalScrollBar()` and `view->verticalScrollBar()` to obtain `QScrollBar*` objects. Connect to `valueChanged(int)` signal of these objects to track scrolling.

Comment: Are you sure about the QScrollBar connections ? I got this while compiling :
  `connect(horizontalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), ((QGraphicsView*)this), SLOT(scrollMoved(int)));`

`graphicScene.cpp:30:107: error: no matching function for call to ‘GraphicScene::connect(QScrollBar*, const char [19], QGraphicsView*, const char [18])’`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include `QScrollBar` :)

Comment: Man thanks a lot, you saved me some hours :D i tried tons of different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Also, note the viewport contains a function to fit an area of the scene into the view so that you can see all of that area using: -

```
void QGraphicsView::fitInView(const QRectF & rect, Qt::AspectRatioMode aspectRatioMode = Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio)
```

Comment: Incorrect. `sceneRect` returns the total area that can be visible in the view on all scrollbar positions. The scene rect can be larger than viewport and doesn't depend on scrollbar positions.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. You're right, thanks for pointing it out. I've edited that part of the answer.